# QUALITY- how I can reduce or increase quality?

Tags: edit-mode

I have an actually simply question. Pleas tell me how I can reduce/increase generally the quality. So that I must not render so long or whatever- pls. name all possibilities:) (or the most important) 
Thank you in front :D

Comment: This is a poorly structured question. There is  not enough detail. But, generally, quality is adjusted in the render settings of whatever renderer your using. But, render time is determined by a number of factors.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the quality/render times several ways.

-In the Render Panel under “Dimensions” reduce the “Resolution”.

-If you are rendering with “Cycles” in the Render Panel under “Sampling” reduce the number of render samples.

-Keep the number of vertices in you scene as low as possible.

-More info here if you are using cycles

http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/#.U8bQthbFPG5

[image]